# Serializing an object as Json

Tags: c#, json

I'm attempting to serialize an object as Json.  The error returned by the code below is "An instance of type string cannot be assigned to a variable of type JsonResult".  Can someone explain what I've done wrong? I thought serialize() accepts an object and that's what I am passing it.

```
    public class SummaryStats
    {
        public int rating_number { get; set; }
        public string rating_label { get; set; }
        public string rating_view { get; set; }
        public int max_stars { get; set; }
        public int star_1_rating { get; set; }
        public int star_2_rating { get; set; }
        public int star_3_rating { get; set; }
        public int star_4_rating { get; set; }
        public int star_5_rating { get; set; }
    }
    public JsonResult GetSummaryStats()
    {
        SummaryStats stats = new SummaryStats();
        stats.star_1_rating = 1;
        stats.star_2_rating = 1;
        stats.star_3_rating = 1;
        stats.star_4_rating = 11;
        stats.star_5_rating = 20;



        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        JsonResult output = json.Serialize(stats);

        return output;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is within a `Controller` derivative, just do:

```
return Json(stats);
```

The rest is handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Serializing your class :

```
[Serializable()]        
public class SummaryStats
{
...
}
```